# Delimited string of ids as a field or a separate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have a database in which I store a large amount of user-created products.
The user can also create "views" which works as a container holding these products, lets call them categories.
It would be simple if each product had a category-field containing the id of the category, however each product can be added to multiple categories so that doesn't work.
Presently I solve this by having a string-field "products" in the category-table which is a comma-separated list of product-ids.
What I'm wondering is basically if it's "okay" to do it this way? Is it generally accepted? Will it cause some kind of problem I'm not realizing?
Would it be better to create another table named something like productsInCategories which has 2 fields, one with a category-id and one with product-id and link them together this way?
Will one of these methods perform better or be better in some other way?

I'm using sqlce at the moment if that matters, but that will most likely change soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the second option: a separate table.

Makes it easier to handle if you need to query from the product perspective. Also the join to the categories will be simple and fast. This is exactly what relational databases are made for.

Imagine a simple query like what categories a product is in. With your solution you need to check all categories one by one, parse the csv-list of each category to find the products. With a separate table it is one clean query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I appreciate it. I changed into this way and it definitely feels like the right way now. I just asked another qrelated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496850/conditional-insert