# Conditional Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

This is a kind of follow-up to my other question: [Delimited string of ids as a field or a separate table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495364/delimited-string-of-ids-as-a-field-or-a-separate-table)

I have a database containing a table of products, one of categories, and one like "productsInCategories"(described in the other question). The productsInCategories-table has two fields: productId and categoryId.

When I want to get all the products from a category I do something similar to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
INNER JOIN ProductsInCategories
ON Products.Id=ProductsInCategories.productId
```

Its working well and I think it's the right way to do it?

Anyway, I'm unsure of how to insert new products the best way.
The client sends properties of a new product, and an id of the category it should be added to. The server executes an INSERT query on the Products-table, and also one on the ProductsInCategories where it inserts the id of the newly created product and category-id the client specified.
The problem with this is that a user of course could send custom data, and specify a category not belonging to him.

Should I first do a SELECT and get the userID of the category which the user specified, and check if it matches with the id of the current user? Or should the ProductsInCategories also contain a field for userId(seems redundant?)? Or preferably, is there a way to verify this in the SELECT query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a way to put a kind of conditional in the insert-query. This is how:

```
INSERT INTO productsInCategories (categoryId, productId)
SELECT id,@0 FROM Categories WHERE userId=@1 AND id=@2

@0=Last insert id (the product inserted prior to this query)
@1=The user id
@2=The category id supplied by the client
```

If the client supplies a spooked category-id then no record will be found by the select statement(unless that category is owned by the same user, which in case we don't care about) and nothing will be inserted. Then we'll just check how many rows were inserted(the execute-function of WebMatrix.Data.Database which I use returns the count of records affected as an int which will be 0 then) and if none then roll back.

The INSERT with the nested SELECT looks funny, at least to me. With no "Values()" and the second unrelated parameter is in the middle of it. I haven't really looked up anything about that and don't have any facts but I think that's because the select-query basically returns a Values()-object so we'll have to omit it, and that's why we can't put additional parameters after the select-query too. Instead we pass them to the select-query as constants so it'll just put them in the Values-object it returns.

Comment: You answered your own question correctly.  :-)  Regarding the transaction question raised in the comments below, it depends on whether it's OK to have products that are not in categories.  If the product must be in a category then, yes, the two INSERTS should be inside one user-defined transaction.  Else it's OK as is.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you always validate data coming from a client before storing into the database. Only after the data is checked and found correct you do the database operation. In this case you have two inserts. So you have to do it in one transaction with a commit statement at the end. I must admit I am not familiar with sql-server-ce but I am sure that it has a transaction commit/rollback feature as any other sql database.

Comment: Thanks. Right now I blindly set the product-properties from what the client supplies. It's validated on client side, but if one sends invalid, custom data then it would produce an error when trying to insert a string into an int-field for instance. I could validate on client-side before the INSERT query but not sure if that matters? Anyway, I'm basically just trying to get away from that extra select-query where I check if the category belongs to the user, and instead somehow put the check inside the productsInCategories-INSERT-query if possible and eventually roll back if that INSERT fails

Comment: Do not worry too much about this. You could try to INSERT and handle when it fails. But never rely on anything validated in the client. Do it all again at the server. Validating in the "positive" approach of insert and a constraint or trigger will stop it is okay but you need to decide how you do it. Both ways work.